# How to hand-engineer features of TfidfVectorizer in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to cluster documents by keywords. I'm using the following code to make a `tdidf-matrix`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.8, max_features=1000,
                             min_df=0.07, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, 
                             ngram_range=(1,2))

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
```

`print(tfidf_matrix.shape)`
returns `(567, 209)`, meaning there are 567 documents, each of which has some mixture of the 209 feature words detected by the scikit-learn TdidfVectorizer.

Now, I used `terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()` to get a list of the terms. Running `print(len(terms))` gives `209`

Many of these words are unnecessary for the task, and they add noise to the clustering. I have went through the list by hand and extracted the meaningful feature names, resulting in a new `terms` list. Now, running `print(len(terms))` gives `67`

However, running `tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)` still gives a shape of `(567, 209)`, which means the `fit_transform(documents)` function is still using the noisy list of 209 terms rather than the hand-selected list of 67 terms.

How can I get the `tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)` function to run using the list of 67 hand-selected terms? I'm thinking that perhaps this will require me to add at least one function to the Scikit-Learn package on my machine, correct?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. If you have identified a list of stopwords (you called them "unnecessary for the task"), just put them into the `stop_words` parameter of the `TfidfVectorizer` to ignore them in the creation of the bag of words.
   Note however that the predefined english stopwords won't be used any more if you set the `stop_words` parameter to your custom list. If you want to combine the predefined english list with your additional stopwords, just add the two lists:

   ```
   from sklearn.feature_extraction.stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
   stop_words = list(ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS) + ['your','additional', 'stopwords']
   tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words) # add your other params here
   ```
2. If you have a fixed vocabulary and only want these words to be counted (i.e. your `terms` list), just set the `vocabulary` parameter of `TfidfVectorizer`:

   ```
   tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=terms) # add your other params here
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out how to solve the problem on the level I requested in the questions. However, I figured out a hacky solution that works for now.

I was able to use my hand-crafted set of terms by doing the following:

1) From `terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()`, print out `terms`.

2) Make a list called `unwanted_terms` and filling it by hand with unwanted terms from step 1.

3) Towards the top of my document, where I import stopwords:

```
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
```

Add my list of unwanted terms to stopwords:

```
for item in not_needed_words_list:
    stopwords.append(item)
```

Comment: Another way is that you can use `'vocabulary'` parameter of TfidfVectorizer for your selected 67 features.